# 2-D contourplot on specific geometry in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a contourplot of a specific geometry (a polygon). I have the corordinates for the corners and a number of points inside this polygon with 1-D parameters that I want to interpolate to a contourplot. I'm able to plot the distribution of the paramater but the image comes out as a square (as I do not know how to specify my geometry). 
Needless to say I'm a Python beginner...

I use the following code at the moment;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

r = np.array([[0, 0, 1.0000], [0, 1.0000, 0], [1.0000, 0, 0], [0, 0.7071, 0.7071],
[0, -0.7071, 0.7071],[0.7071, 0, 0.7071], [-0.7071, 0, 0.7071], [0.7071, 0.7071, 0], 
[-0.7071, 0.7071, 0], [0.8361,  0.3879, 0.3879], [-0.8361, 0.3879, 0.3879], 
[0.8361, -0.3879, 0.3879], [-0.8361, -0.3879, 0.3879], [0.3879, 0.8361, 0.3879],
[-0.3879, 0.8361, 0.3879], [0.3879, -0.8361, 0.3879], [-0.3879, -0.8361, 0.3879],
[0.3879, 0.3879, 0.8361], [-0.3879, 0.3879, 0.8361], [0.3879, -0.3879, 0.8361],
[-0.3879, -0.3879, 0.8361], [-1.0000, 0, 0], [-0.7071, -0.7071, 0], [0, -1.0000, 0],
[0.7071, -0.7071, 0]])

xx = r[:,0]
yy = r[:,1]
zz = r[:,2]

xxi, yyi = np.linspace(xx.min(), xx.max(), 100), np.linspace(yy.min(), yy.max(), 100)
xxi, yyi = np.meshgrid(xxi, yyi)

rbff = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(xx, yy, zz, function='linear')
zzi = rbff(xxi, yyi)
plt.imshow(zzi, vmin=zz.min(), vmax=zz.max(), origin='lower',
       extent=[xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()])
plt.scatter(xx, yy, c=zz)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is cheating, but nevertheless: you can add something like that

```
zzi = rbff(xxi, yyi)
zzi[zzi<0.1]=nan
```

and play with the value (0.1 at the moment).

Comment: Yes, or `zzm = np.ma.masked_where(zzi<0.1, zzi)` if you don't want to kill the data in the array (just cover it with a mask).

Answer (score 0):

If your polygon is convex, you can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to get the mask area:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

r = np.array([[0, 0, 1.0000], [0, 1.0000, 0], [1.0000, 0, 0], [0, 0.7071, 0.7071],
[0, -0.7071, 0.7071],[0.7071, 0, 0.7071], [-0.7071, 0, 0.7071], [0.7071, 0.7071, 0], 
[-0.7071, 0.7071, 0], [0.8361,  0.3879, 0.3879], [-0.8361, 0.3879, 0.3879], 
[0.8361, -0.3879, 0.3879], [-0.8361, -0.3879, 0.3879], [0.3879, 0.8361, 0.3879],
[-0.3879, 0.8361, 0.3879], [0.3879, -0.8361, 0.3879], [-0.3879, -0.8361, 0.3879],
[0.3879, 0.3879, 0.8361], [-0.3879, 0.3879, 0.8361], [0.3879, -0.3879, 0.8361],
[-0.3879, -0.3879, 0.8361], [-1.0000, 0, 0], [-0.7071, -0.7071, 0], [0, -1.0000, 0],
[0.7071, -0.7071, 0]])

xx = r[:,0]
yy = r[:,1]
zz = r[:,2]

xxi, yyi = np.linspace(xx.min(), xx.max(), 100), np.linspace(yy.min(), yy.max(), 100)
xxi, yyi = np.meshgrid(xxi, yyi)

rbff = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(xx, yy, zz, function='linear')
zzi = rbff(xxi, yyi)
mask = np.isnan(scipy.interpolate.griddata(np.c_[xx, yy], zz, (xxi, yyi)))
zzi[mask] = np.nan
plt.imshow(zzi, vmin=zz.min(), vmax=zz.max(), origin='lower',
       extent=[xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()])
plt.scatter(xx, yy, c=zz)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]